# Using 'bigfoot' and 'hyperref' package - PDF bookmarks reference to wrong page/line

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, footnotes, bookmarks, bigfoot

Please compile the following document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\blindtext

\blindtext 

\blindtext 

\blindtext

\blindtext  

\blindtext

\blindtext    

\section{MySection}

\blindtext  

\blindtext  

\end{document}
```

Open it in your Adobe Reader and use the 'two pages' view.
The first section 'MySection' will be on the third page, so not visible if you open the document.
If you use PDF bookmark for navigating to 'MySection', the page does not change!
In Adobe 'single page' view, the page will change to page 2.
In a 'continuous ' view, the view will change to the line right before page 3.

To cut a long story short, the bookmark seems to be one line before the section header.

Remove the `bigfoot` package and everything works as expected. I want to use the package, because it solves some footnote problems I have.

Do you know any tweaks or fixes I can use in order to use the package **and** correct PDF bookmarks.

Quote from `bigfoot` documentation:
*Purpose of this package is to provide a one-stop solution to almost all problems related to footnotes. You can use it as a drop-in replacement of the manyfoot package, but without many of its shortcomings, and quite a few features of its own. It uses the existing document class layouts for footnotes, so you can usually use it without having to worry about the looks.*

Comment: It seems a bug in `bigfoot`; I'm afraid you need to tweak it manually by adding `\pagebreak` in front of the sections that fall at the start of a page.